# How to solve "ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (3, 5) instead." for naive Bayes?

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, regression, naivebayes

```
from sklearn.model_selection import  train_test_split

X = data.drop('Vickers Hardness\n(HV0.5)', axis=1)
y = data['Vickers Hardness\n(HV0.5)']

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3)
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB 
gnb = GaussianNB()
gnb.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = gnb.predict(X_test)
```

> ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (3, 5) instead.

Used data:

[image: used data]

How to rectify this error in naive bayes? how can I put y in 1D array?

Comment: According to the sklearn docs it looks like GaussianNB expects the targets to be a vector.

Answer (score 3):

The assignments of the train/test split are not ordered right, use:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3)
```